# Shared Preferences crashing application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Today I have somehow broken my android application. After restarting multiple times, the shared preferences file got corrupted and I couldn't launch the application without crash. It only got fixed after reinstallation.

Anybody had this problem before?

```
 SharedPreferencesImpl: Cannot read
 /data/user/0/fi.millisecond.canvas.flow/shared_prefs/fi.millisecond.canvas.flow.xml
     org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:unknown @1:9 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b2a3b47) 
         at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:436)
         at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:321)
         at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:1405)
         at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:740)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:150)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
         at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:120)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is your exact question?

Comment: The sentence which appears before question mark.

Comment: I assume that you want to *solve* the problem or *prevent* it in the future, instead of knowing who have experienced it before. Am I right?

Comment: First of all I'd like to find a root cause of the problem, because I don't know if it could happen in production environment or is it only a debugging issue. Maybe the compiler have accidentally overwritten some important part, I don't know.

Comment: That's a better and more clear question! Are you writing a lot or large values to the shared preferences?

Comment: No. I have only 10 values stored and all of them are simple strings, longs and booleans.

Comment: I regret not saving preferences xml file because when I looked at it in device file explorer, it was perfectly normal apart from having multiple square symbols on the beginning and at the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody had this problem before?

Well, I never had this issue.

> First of all I'd like to find a root cause of the problem

You mentioned in the comments that you are not writing a lot of values to the `SharedPreferences`. I assume that the root of the problem is that your application was restarted by the IDE while it might was busy writing to your `SharedPreferences`.

> because I don't know if it could happen in production environment or
>   is it only a debugging issue

In my experience hot reloading is always quite buggy while developing apps, and I think that you were unlucky, hence the preferences file got corrupted.

I would recommend you to play a bit around with a release version of your app. If the problem persists, which will be unlikely, I would investigate your code which writes to your `SharedPreferences`. If possible add a check for an `Exception` as well in that case.

When saving, you could also get the return value of the operation. Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit(). I know that Android Studio might complain about using `commit()`. However, it's the only way to know if writing your preferences has succeeded.